# replay a video inside a React-bootstrap Carousel

Tags: reactjs, carousel, react-bootstrap, reactstrap

I have a React-bootstrap Carousels, each slide contains component and there is a video in each of these components, the video is auto played and looped,
I'm trying to make the video **play from start when it gets shown in the slider** and not continue where it originally started from.
according to [React-bootstrap documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/carousel/#carousel-props) there is a property called `onSlid` : `Callback fired when a slide transition ends.`
I want to start the video over via a callback function but I don't know how to write this function.
This is the code :

```
import Carousel from "react-bootstrap/Carousel";
import { useState } from "react";
import componant1 from "../SliderComponents/component1 ";
import componant2 from "../SliderComponents/component2 ";
import componant3 from "../SliderComponents/component3 ";

const Hero = () => {
  const handler = () => {
    // here is where I'm trying to start the video from second 0
  };
  return (
    <div className="Hero">
      <div>
        <Carousel
          controls={false}
          fade={true}
          interval={5500}
          pause={false}
          className="hero-slider"
          onSlid={handler} //a callback fired when a slide transition ends.
        >
          <Carousel.Item>
            <component1 />
          </Carousel.Item>
          <Carousel.Item>
            <component2 />
          </Carousel.Item>
          <Carousel.Item>
            <component3 />
          </Carousel.Item>
        </Carousel>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Hero;
```

The components that has the videos looks like this :

```
import videos from "../../../assets/videos/index";

    const component1= () => {
      return (
        <div className="wrapper">
          <video
            className="slider-video"
            src={videos.video1}
            loop
            autoPlay
            muted
            loading="lazy"
          ></video>
        </div>
      );
    };
    export default component1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution although I think there is a better way to solve this,
I will write it here anyway.
first of all, I have put the videos directly inside the slider and then I have used vanilla JavaScript to select all the videos and reset their time when the slide changes with the help of  `onSlid` property

```
import Carousel from "react-bootstrap/Carousel";
import videos from "../../assets/videos/index";

const Hero = () => {
  const sliderVideos = document.querySelectorAll(".slider-video");
  const handler = () => {
    sliderVideos.forEach((video,key) => {
    video.pause();
    video.currentTime = 0;
    video.load();
});
  };
  return (
    <div className="Hero">
      <div>
        <Carousel
          controls={false}
          fade={true}
          interval={5500}
          pause={false}
          className="hero-slider"
          onSlid={handler}
        >
          <Carousel.Item>
             <video
            className="slider-video"
            src={videos.video1}
            loop
            autoPlay
            muted
            loading="lazy"
          ></video>
          </Carousel.Item>
          <Carousel.Item>
            <video
            className="slider-video"
            src={videos.video2}
            loop
            autoPlay
            muted
            loading="lazy"
          ></video>
          </Carousel.Item>
          <Carousel.Item>
            <video
            className="slider-video"
            src={videos.video3}
            loop
            autoPlay
            muted
            loading="lazy"
          ></video>
          </Carousel.Item>
        </Carousel>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Hero;
```

There is a problem with this method,
`onSlid` property calls `handler` function after the fade ends which makes a ~0.5s delay before the function `handler` executes